# Register script version not showing

Tags: cache, wp-register-script

I want to implement cache busting on a specific script, but the version is not added to the url as query vars.

Here is the code I'm using :

```
wp_register_script( 'custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.min.js', array('jquery','modernizr'), filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory().'/js/custom.min.js' ), true );
```

I'm using the filemtime function to get the timestamp of the last modification as my version.

But in the source I get :

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/app/themes/MyTheme/js/custom.min.js'></script>
```

Where I would want something like `http://example.com/app/themes/MyTheme/js/custom.min.js?v=1472031892`

Comment: Try and check if this `filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory().'/js/custom.min.js' )` is returning any value as it might return just *false*.

Also try 'time()' instead and see if you get you desirable version

Answer (score 0):

I can verify this is working for me and it looks much like the code you've provided.

Perhaps there is somewhere else you are defining your script. Can you give it a new handle name to check (`'custom-xyz'`)?

Also, can you test the output of [`filemtime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) to see what it's outputting? I've added a "`v`" in front of it in case it returns `false`.

```
$ver = "v" . filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory().'/js/custom.min.js' );

wp_register_script( 'custom',

    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.min.js',

    array( 'jquery','modernizr' ),

    $ver,

    true);

wp_enqueue_script( 'custom' );
```

---

If, for the odd reason you can't get it to work correctly when you register, you could potentially filter the tag on output using [`script_loader_tag`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/script_loader_tag/) and some regex or [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

```
wp_register_script( 'custom',

    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.min.js',

    array( 'jquery','modernizr' ),

    '%%CACHE_BUSTER%%',

    true);

wp_enqueue_script( 'custom' );

function script_tag_cache_buster( $tag, $handle, $src ) {

    if ( 'custom' === $handle ) {
        return str_replace( '%%CACHE_BUSTER%%', "v" . filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory().'/js/custom.min.js'), $tag );
    }

    return $tag;
}

add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'script_tag_cache_buster', 10, 3 );
```